# Laravel uses wrong primary key updating mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

I set a custom string typed primary key in Laravel 6.x, calling
`$node=Node::create()` is fine, but when calling `$node->save()` later to update, it uses `where ‘instanceId’=0` to match the primary key, which throw an exception with MySQL 1292 error.

For table schema (migrate):

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('nodes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('instanceId')->primary();
        $table->string('regionId')->nullable();
        $table->string('privateIp')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('publicIp')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('dnsRecordId')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('status')->default(0);
        $table->unsignedInteger('userId');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

For model definition:

```
/**
 * The primary key associated with the table.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'instanceId';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'instanceId',
    'regionId',
    'privateIp',
    'publicIp',
    'dnsRecordId',
    'status',
    'userId',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'userId' => 'integer',
];
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys  make sure to adjust the other properties related to the primary key if it isn't an autoincrement integer on the model

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't set the value of instanceId before calling $node->save().
so it looks like $node->instanceId was null and since instanceId is a primary key it can't be null.
To prevent such issue, you need to set the value of instanceId before saving it or else you can set the default random value of the instanceId in the createSchema.

$node->instanceId = str_random(20);

Thanks

Comment: It is not Null, it is set at early create(), I also double checked inside MySQL. Also, if it is null, the function calling all these will early return, there are logic for this.

Comment: Can you plz try to set the default value of instanceId in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to lagbox, this is really a RTFM problem.
When using string primary key `$incrementing=false` and `$keyType=‘string’` are required, otherwise Laravel will assume the primary key is self incrementing integer.